# Is it possible to customize the transdissolve effect?

Tags: beamer, transition

This code uses the `\transdissolve` effect:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
   \transdissolve[duration=.1]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
           \only<1>{\draw[fill=red] (current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);}
           \only<2>{\draw[fill=blue] (current page.south west)rectangle(current page.north east);}
        \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The effect decompose the frame into small rectangles that change color.

Is it possible to customize the effect changing the size of the rectangles?

Answer (score 6):

Transitions are offered by PDF, not LaTeX.  When available, you can however define the duration and the direction as options.  For example, `\transdissolve[duration=0.2]` or `\transglitter[direction=90]`.  The duration is given in seconds and the direction in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the overlay animations are also something from the pdf format (in interaction with the viewer) itself, so latex does not have influence on the size of the rectangles.